# option followed by a option in getopt [where the earlier option was expecting a value]

Tags: c, getopt

I have a doubt if we have two option -a and -c  and option -a needs to have a value and no value for -c

now if i give  ->testopt -a -c  [testopt is program]

then my program takes -c as a value for -a . is there a way where i can make sure that a option with value does not have other options as its values ?

the thing is that the system accepts - one keyword's value as another keyword which i need to prevent .
e.g. - testopt -a -c. in this case there was a mandatory argument (value ) for -a and no  value for -c.. but i my getopt interprets this as "-c" is the value for "-a" how can  i throw a error on this using getopt.

Comment: Please add the code where you define the command line options for `getopt`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : sure i shall do that . thanks for the tip.

Comment: @HonkyTonk : sorry will not be able to do that ... proprietary code...
but the thing is that the system accepts - one keyword's value as another keyword which i need to prevent .
e.g. - testopt -a -c. in this case there was a mandatory argument (value ) for -a and no  value for -c.. but i my getopt interprets this as "-c" is the value for "-a" how can  i throw a error on this using getopt.

Comment: I'd say that the string you send to `getopt` to define the options is safe to post if you replace any actual names with placeholders. Then it's possible to see what you've actually done and that would help since I have trouble understanding your description. Your "error" might very well be a coding error...

Comment: @HonkyTonk : here is the getopt string : 

getopt(argc, argv, "Rc:dfh:I:a:i:l:Lt:np:qrs:vMUC:Ft:V:")

Comment: consider a command : testopt country XYZ city PQR
for my program country is mapped to "-a" and city is mapped to "-i"
problem happens when you enter : testopt country city
so what happens is according to mapping country is mapped to "-a" and city which is actually value for country is added as "-i" 
and the getopt processes only one option i.e. "-a" and take "-i" as its value which is incorrect.
i know its my mistake in parsing ... but it can not be changed

Comment: is it possible to have a check using getopt where such case arises it raises some error .i.e value of a option like "-a" can not be another option "-i" or any other option

Comment: @HonkyTonk : i have explained with an example... can you please try now...

Answer (score 1):

You get `-c` as the value for the `-a` option because you specified `-a` to have a value. If you call your program with the options the other way around

```
$ testopt -c -a
```

then `getopt` will return with a `'?'` indicating that an option value is missing (as per the [`getopt` manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getopt.html)), and an error will be printed on the console.

Unfortunately there is no way of telling `getopt` that an argument has an optional value, then you have to implement your own option parser.

Comment: The options argument is a string that specifies the option characters that are valid for this program. An option character in this string can be followed by a colon (‘:’) to indicate that it takes a required argument. If an option character is followed by two colons (‘::’), its argument is optional; this is a GNU extension. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt I think i have used it with optional arguments in open source project dnrd