# Getopt() Accepting Other Option as Argument in C

Tags: c, command-line, getopt, command-line-arguments

So I searched high and low for an answer to this question and all I could find was someone who poorly asked the same question 2 years ago and was never really answered ([option followed by a option in getopt [where the earlier option was expecting a value]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617749/option-followed-by-a-option-in-getopt-where-the-earlier-option-was-expecting-a)).

Currently, I am writing a program that is supposed to accept command line options and arguments.
The command is supposed to create and manipulate an archive file supplied through the command line. I am using `getopt()`. The usage for the command is `oscar [options] [archive-file] [member files]` however some of the options do not require arguments. Such as a '-v' flag which stands for verbose and simply causes other actions in the file to spit out more print statements than the default.

Here is my code for using getopt():

```
 //declaring some variables to be used by getopt
 18     extern char *optarg;    //pointer to options that require an argument
 19     extern int optind;      //index into main()'s argument list (argv[])
 20
 21     int getOptReturn = 0;   //int that stores getopt's return (used to check if it is done parsing)
 22     int error = 0;          //flag for '?' case if getopt doesn't receive proper input
 23
 24     //flags for all the options
 25     int a_flag, A_flag, v_flag, C_flag, d_flag, e_flag, h_flag,
 26     m_flag, o_flag, t_flag, T_flag, E_flag, V_flag, u_flag = 0;
 27
 28     int i;                  //for loops index
 29
 30     char *aname;
 31
 32     //while parsing options
 33     while((getOptReturn = getopt(argc, argv, "a:A:Cd:e:E:hm:otTu:vV")) != -1)
 34     {
 35         //debugging
 36         printf("optind: %d, option: %c, optarg: %s \n", optind, argv[optind], optarg);
 37         printf("%d\n", argc);
 38
 39         //switch options and set appropriate flags
 40         switch(getOptReturn)
 41         {
 42             case 'a':
 43                 printf("-a option received\n");
 44                 //turn add flag on
 45                 a_flag = 1;
 46                 aname = optarg;
 47                 printf("argument supplied to -a: %s \n", aname);
 48                 break;
 49             case 'A':
 50                 printf("-A option received\n");
 51                 //turn add all flag on
 52                 A_flag = 1;
 53                 aname = optarg;
 54                 printf("argument supplied to -A: %s \n", aname);
 55                 break;
 56             case 'v':
 57                 printf("-v option received\n");
 58                 //turn verbose flag on
 59                 v_flag = 1;
 60                 printf("verbose flag turned on!\n");
 61                 break;
```

Now the problem that I'm facing is that the order I'm passing the option characters in currently matters when it is not supposed to.

For example:

If i call the function with `./oscar -va archive` the code functions properly and `v` causes the v flag to be turned on, and `a` is processed with `archive` as the argument because I required `a` to have an argument inside of `getopt()`.

However, if I call the function with `./oscar -av archive` the code reads in `a` and assigns `v` as its required argument instead of reading `v` as an option and using `archive` as the argument for `a`.

Is there any way I can tell `getopt()` to skip over other option values in argv[] so that I can call the function from the command line with all sorts of combinations and not worry about order such as:

`./oscar -avo archive file1 file2 file3...`

`./oscar -a A v archive file1 file2...`

Comment: Whoops, sorry about the bad edit. I accidentally removed all numbers from the question, not just the line numbers.

Comment: That's the standard behaviour of program options as specified by POSIX guidelines. "One or more options without option-arguments, followed by at most one option that takes an option-argument, should be accepted when grouped behind one '-' delimiter." Don't break standards.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I figured out how to get around it and handle it manually by using optind and argc, but thanks for the answer. It was really bugging me.

Comment: I don't mean to sound overly critical, but please tell me this is not serious. I don't want to type `-a Archive` and have it parsed as option `-a`, option `-A`, argument to `-a` "rc", option `-h`, argument to `-A` "i", option `-v`, option `-e`. I'd expect it to be option `-a`, followed by its argument "Archive". If this isn't merely an exercise in option parsing, I hope to never use your program because I'd be tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to pass command line options correctly. `getopt` works the way it does for a reason. Please don't break your users' expected behavior.

Comment: It's completely serious. It's an assignment for my operating systems class and that's how the professor wants us to use the program. Using his example program, you can call it with a required option first and it still works like a charm. My professor also said that he used `getopt` so I was just wondering.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319002/7971629) worked for me, was having a similar issue.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319002/7971629) worked for me, was having a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to user `n.m.`'s comment, this is just how command line arguments are supposed to behave as specified by the POSIX guidelines.

From his comment:

> "One or more options without option-arguments, followed by at most one option that takes an option-argument, should be accepted when grouped behind one '-' delimiter."

If you desire the functionality I was looking for, you need to use the external variable that getopt supplies you with: `optind` paired with `argc` and `argv[]` to manually handle more options that require arguments.

Thanks for reading.